# Boot2Docker/Fig mounted volume not refreshing

Tags: nginx, docker, boot2docker, fig

I am using fig to mount my OS X directory through the boot2docker host vm. I am using the already provided Users directory.  Try the following:

/code/Tryme.txt - "Hello there"

1. Volume: /Users//code:/code
2. Start up an nginx server and serve the code from /code.
3. Get the file via nginx: content is "Hello there"
4. Change the content of the Tryme.txt - "Hello foobar"
5. When you get the file again, you get the original text: "Hello there"

So What am I missing?  Any ideas?  If I take the container down and bring it back up, the file is as it should be. When I nsenter the image, the file is changed as it should be as well.

Ideas?

Thanks.

**Update**: 
 I have seen this as well with my application code serving the file up and it still doesn't change. I wanted this to be a dev environment for quick turn around, but it doesn't seem to work like expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to add [this configuration](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/virtualbox.html) in nginx:

```
sendfile off;
```

Personally, I avoid serving anything out of a shared folder because of these types of inconsistencies. Run a simple watch script that kicks off an rsync inside your container from your shared folder volume to a container-only volume whenever anything changes. Then, have nginx serve from your container-only volume (`/var/www` below). Example fig:

```
volumes:
 - ~/code:/code
 - /var/www
```